# Jekyll not serving site locally

Tags: ruby, macos, jekyll

**Configuration:** OSX 10.9.1, ruby 2.1.1 via [RVM](https://rvm.io/)

I have created a new [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) site via the command `jekyll new sitename`.

I then enter that directory and issue the command `jekyll serve`.

I get the following notice:

```
Configuration file: /Users/George/sitename/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/George/sitename
       Destination: /Users/George/sitename/_site
      Generating... done.
    Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

However when attempting to visit `http://localhost:4000/` or `http://0.0.0.0:4000/` my browser endlessly attempts to load the page.

I have checked and the site was built correctly including an `index.html` in `/Users/George/sitename/_site/`.

The `_config.yml` looks like so:

```
name: sitename
markdown: maruku
pygments: true
```

Does anyone know why Jekyll could be failing to serve the site but not throwing any errors?

**Edit:** If I change the port to `6000` and attempt to serve it then my browser instantly gives a `page not found` so there must be something interfering with port `4000` however the issue still stands.

Answer (score 5):

It's likely that something else is using port `4000` on your computer. You can find out by running the following command:

```
sudo lsof -i :4000
```

As you can run the server on another port, we'll move on to the next issue, setting the baseurl. In your `_config.yml` you can specify which `baseurl` to use, this will be the url from which all pages are served, so if you had `baseurl: http://myawesomesite.com`, Jekyll will expect them to be accessed from that url.

As you're working locally, you have two options:

Set the `baseurl` to `/` in your `_config.yml`:

```
baseurl: /
```

Launch Jekyll with the `--baseurl` flag:

```
$ jekyll serve -w --baseurl '/'
```

Additionally, you could specify the port as a flag:

```
$ jekyll server -w --baseurl '/' --port 4000
```

If you want further information about what's going on when you run `jekyll`, you can run the command with the `--trace` flag:

```
$ jekyll server -w --trace
```

Comment: Thanks, a TomTom application was listening on 4000. However I have switched to port 6000 which is empty, tried modifying the `baseurl` property and used the `--trace` flag but it still does not work and doesn't provide any additional information.

Comment: If the config file in the question is correct, I don't think `baseurl` can be the problem since Jekyll defaults to serving from `/`.

Comment: Ok... I switched to port 8080 and it worked. Weird because `sudo lsof -i :6000` says nothing runs there but wikipedia stated `6000` may be used by X11. Now it's working.